# Adding value to text field in Bootstrap3 popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**THE PROBLEM**

I have a popover which I fill with content from a hidden element. When the popover is shown I want to prefill the text fields with data which is contained elsewhere.

The popover shows correctly just no data in the text fields.

**I'M TRYING**

```
<!-- change dob1 content -->
<div id="dob1_iq" style="display: none">
    <input type="text" id="iq__dob1-day" value="">
    <input type="text" id="iq__dob1-month" value="">
    <input type="text" id="iq__dob1-year" value="">
</div>
```

I know the data is there as I see it in console log:

```
$('.dob1_iq').popover({
    html : true,
    content: function() {
        return $('#dob1_iq').html();
    }
})
.on('show.bs.popover', function() { 
    console.log('day is ' + $('#qq__dob1-day').val()); // <- this shows value is there in console
    $('#iq__dob1-day').val($('#qq__dob1-day').val()); // stays blank
    $('#iq__dob1-month').val($('#qq__dob1-month').val()); // stays blank
    $('#iq__dob1-year').val($('#qq__dob1-year').val()); // stays blank
});
```

Is there a way to do this?

**SEE IT IN ACTION**

[Here's a bootply to see it in action](http://www.bootply.com/QNnBHAa3qg)

**UPDATE**

Thinking it could be because the elements are not in the DOM I also tried the following but that failed too:

```
$(document).find("#iq__dob1-day").val($('#qq__dob1-day').val());
```

**UPDATE 2**

I checked if the element I'm trying to add the value to actually exists, and it does:

```
// this gives "does it exist 1"    
console.log('does it exist ' + $('#iq__dob1-day').length);
```

Comment: do you absolutely need it in the square boxes? I was able to do it without the square boxes. I can post my answer so you take a look.

Comment: Its a form so yeah, it's for editing

Comment: you want to be able to edit in the popover?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't post but on blur it will update some hidden fields

Comment: I see. because I had this: http://www.bootply.com/jLFdIQCqqp

Comment: Yeah I already do that when showing data which can't edited - very weird issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strange. Can't explain but if you want it to work you can use `attr`

This works fine:

```
$('#iq__dob1-day').attr("value", $('#qq__dob1-day').val()); // stays blank
$('#iq__dob1-month').attr("value", $('#qq__dob1-month').val()); // stays blank
$('#iq__dob1-year').attr("value", $('#qq__dob1-year').val()); // stays blank
```

**EDIT**: `val()` does not work as expected as id's are duplicated. I've added `$('#dob1_iq').show();` and that explains what's happening: http://www.bootply.com/B6ULMiPGbc#

Comment: Hmmm, yeah it does... it is technically slower though, but that's not a big problem right now - thanks also to @CodingEnthusiast for trying to help

Comment: And for the record, adding a `name` makes no difference

Comment: Yup, it does not. Still investigating. Very interesting issue.

Answer (score -1):

val() gets or sets the object's property 'value'.properties wont render in html.
so when we use .html() values of element will be empty.

one way is to update values of the elements inside the popover-content after popover has been made visible to the user.

```
$('.dob1_iq').popover({
    html : true,
    content: function() {
    return $('#dob1_iq').html();
}
})
.on('shown.bs.popover', function() { 

$('.popover-content #iq__dob1-day').val($('#qq__dob1-day').val()); // stays blank
$('.popover-content #iq__dob1-month').val($('#qq__dob1-month').val()); // stays blank
$('.popover-content #iq__dob1-year').val($('#qq__dob1-year').val()); // stays blank
});
```

.attr() will manipulate the attribute value in DOM so .html() will return element with value as attribute value

```
$('.dob1_iq').popover({
html : true,
content: compile
})

function compile()
{
  $('#dob1_iq #iq__dob1-day').attr('value',$('#qq__dob1-day').val());
  $('#dob1_iq #iq__dob1-month').attr('value',$('#qq__dob1-month').val());
  $('#dob1_iq #iq__dob1-year').attr('value',$('#qq__dob1-year').val());
  return $('#dob1_iq').html() 
}
```